# PHP: using REGEX to get the tablename from a mysql query

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Consider these three mysql statements:

```
select * from Users;
select id, title, value from Blogs;
select id, feelURL, feelTitle from Feeds where id = 1;
```

Now im not very good at REGEX, but i want to get the table name from the mysql query. Could someone possibly create one for me with a little explanation.

Thanks,

Comment: Probably not, SQL isn't a completely trivial language, I think you'll basically need a SQL parser, and I doubt anyone's going to want to write one of those with a regular expression.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why and what for you want to do this? With those example statements it's pretty easy with a regex, but as soon as the statements get just a little more complicated (e.g. joins, quoted table names, etc.), such a solution will break. If you tell us what the purpose is, there might be better solutions to be suggested.

Comment: not sure what your trying to accomplish but would this be more useful ? [mysql_tablename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-tablename.php)

Comment: Many of the answers to not account for the fact that mysql supports the dot notation. So you can have SELECT * FROM YourTable; and also SELECT * FROM YourDB.YourTable. Most of the answers below do not account for the dot notation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_match('/\bfrom\b\s*(\w+)/i',$query,$matches)
```

This will not work if the query has more than 1 table.

Basically the regex searchs for the complete word `FROM` in the query and picks the following word as the table name.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually use MySQL as the parser and get the tablenames in your query no matter how complex your SQL syntax.

(Sorry that this is a late response to your question - I just had the same problem today and found this solution.)

Simply prefix your query with the word EXPLAIN and the results set returned to PHP will include id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra.  The third column is the name of each table in your query.

For example, if your query was:

```
select count(*) from ey_def left join ey_rels on def_id=item_id;
```

Use:

```
explain select count(*) from ey_def left join ey_rels on def_id=item_id;
```

And MySQL will return this to PHP:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ey_def  | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   87 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ey_rels | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  123 |             |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Now you can simply process the results like any other query.

Comment: That is a good way to reuse existing functionality and stay sane with the amount variations your queries might have.

Comment: FYI: This isn't particularly effective if the table names are aliased in the query (via `AS`). For example: `SELECT count(*) FROM ey_def AS eyd LEFT JOIN ey_rels AS eyr ON eyr.def_id=eyd.item_id` will return 'eyd' and 'eyr' as the tables and not the _actual_ table names.

Answer (score 1):

A naive implementation would be this:

```
preg_match("/\s+from\s+`?([a-z\d_]+)`?/i", $query, $match);

echo $query . " => " . $match[1] . "\n";
```

This **will** break when you have a subquery in your SELECT field list (and probably in a few other cases). Or when your table name contains characters beside a-z, numbers and underscores.

Parsing SQL correctly isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

For the query string you gave, the following should do:

```
preg_match_all('/from (\w+)/', $query, $tables);

print_r($tables[1]);

[0] => Users
[1] => Blogs
[2] => Feeds
```

But like pointed out in a comment already, creating a full fledged SQL parser is a non-trivial task. Don't expect this to be usable on any and all queries you throw against it.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I would have seen this earlier... Like the people above me stated, it's non-trivial parsing sql statements. To pick out the table names from a sql string, it would be a better idea to get all the table names first, then find matches in the sql (providing you don't have a million tables in your database). I just so happen to have a function on hand that does just that:

```
/*
  Takes a sql statement and attempts to get a table name from it.
  This assumes a database is already specified in the connection.

  [$sql]: string; SQL statement that was executed
  [$conn]: resource; MySQLi connection resource

  returns table name string
 */  
function get_table_names($sql,$conn){
    //declare variables
    $table_array = array();
    $table_string = "";

    //get all the table names in the selected database
    $sql2 = "SHOW TABLES";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    //display an error if something went wrong
    if (!$result) {
        echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
        exit;
    }

    //fetch the rows and push the table names into $table_array
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        array_push($table_array, $row[0]);
    }

    //loop through all the tables in the database
    foreach($table_array as $table){
        if(strpos($sql,$table)){ //if match is found append to string
            $table_string .= " $table ";
        }
    }

    //return a string of table name matches
    return $table_string;
}
```

Hope that helps someone...

Comment: Return false positive is `table_name' is part of a value (ie: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column='foo bar anotherTable';)

Comment: Yes you're right, but it handles multiple tables that would break the other regex's. In my experience, it's a lot more likely to have select statements spanning across multiple tables than it is to name another table in a column. So yes, not perfect, but IMO, better.

Comment: Btw, I tried writing a regex as well, and you have to account for all the ways that MySQL will accept an insertion for example all these work (this is a problem with tolerant languages):
FROM \`foo\`.\`bar\` WHERE  
FROM \`bar\` WHERE  
FROM\`foo\`.\`bar\` WHERE  
FROM \`foo\` .\`bar\` WHERE  
FROM foo.bar WHERE  
FROM bar WHERE  
... (there is a huge amount of permutations possible)
and the syntax changes with insert statements, delete statements etc. None of the regex's on here can deal with all of the above cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
(SELECT|DELETE|UPDATE|INSERT INTO) (\*|[A-Z0-9_]+)(FROM)?([A-Z0-9_, ]+)
```

It will works with select delete update and insert. If you use tablename1, tablename2 it will return it as a array