# How to turn table names into variables?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get a list of my tables in my database and turn those names into variables, but no matter what I try I get the "unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE" error.
This is the problematic part:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%".$date3."%'");
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1); 

if (isset($row1[0])) {  $01 = $row1[0];} 
if (isset($row1[1])) {  $02 = $row1[1];}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: may be you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468497/php-using-regex-to-get-the-tablename-from-a-mysql-query

Comment: Depending on how `$date3` is assigned you might be open to SQL injections with this code. You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: suppose your table name is user and you need the user as $user or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring because PHP variables cannot start with numbers, only letters or underscores.

If you're going to stick with your current naming convention, try using **$one** instead of **$01**.

**Edit**

Link to docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#language.variables.basics

Comment: Might want to add a link to the manual as well, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php.

Comment: @chris85 Added link.  Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can try following one to
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%".$date3."%'");
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1); 
//$$row1[0] will create a variable with table name
//if $row1[0] hold the value user then $$row1[0] is the variable $user and you can access in below the declaration 
if (isset($row1[0])) {  $$row1[0] = $row1[0];} 
if (isset($row1[1])) {  $$row1[1] = $row1[1];}
```